# iOS Swift - implementation of SplitViewController inside a Container View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm following this tutorial [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173753/uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started-2)

But with one change that I made since the beginning.

I Added a ViewController (and made it the Initial View Controller) and Added a Container View in it.

Then I embed seagued between my View Container and the tutorial's SplitViewController.

And all worked well, until I got to this step:

> Go to to AppDelegate.swift and replace the implementation of application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) with the following:

```
guard let splitViewController = window?.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController,
  let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
  let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as? MasterViewController,
  let detailViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? DetailViewController
  else { fatalError() }

let firstMonster = masterViewController.monsters.first
detailViewController.monster = firstMonster

return true
```

How this code should be modified to work with my case?

Comment: Not having a lot of practice with UISplitViewController, I could advice you (if you are interesting in debugging the code yourself) to separate the chain of 'guard'-ed calls into multiple guarded calls, see which one fails and attempt to deduct what needs to be done, which is a common practice in iOS debugging. That said, each of the statement between `guard` and `else` separated with a comma gets its own `guard` and `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can't get access to uisplitviewcontroller in AppDelegate. Since you are using Container Embedded view like in image below. You get reference of the UISplitviewcontroller from prepareFor segue of your first viewController. So instead of writing code in AppDelegate, try do that in prepare for segue in your initial viewController.

[image]
[image]

Initial ViewController
            class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
            @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            }

            override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

                if segue.identifier == "embedseg" {
                    guard let splitViewController = segue.destination as? UISplitViewController,
                        let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
                        let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as? MasterViewController,
                        let rightNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? UINavigationController,
                        let detailViewController = rightNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController
                        else { fatalError() }

                    let firstMonster = masterViewController.monsters.first
                    detailViewController.monster = firstMonster

                    masterViewController.delegate = detailViewController

                    detailViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                    detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
                }

            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, It worked with a little modification: 
`guard let splitViewController = segue.destination as? UISplitViewController,
 let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
 let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as? MasterViewController,
 let detailViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? DetailViewController
 else { fatalError() }`

Comment: now I see your answer is perfectly correct, I was a step behind embedding the detailViewController.